# Is there a way to get my hamburger menu to be on the right side? (i can get the hamburger there, but not the pop out menu)

Tags: html, css, position, hamburger-menu

```css
#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>

  <ul class="menu__box">
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Team</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The hamburger icon made in css is on the right side and functional, but i cannot seem to get the menu there
I want the menu background, and the contents inside of it to be on the right side of the screen instead of the default left.
ofcourse i also want the animation to come from the right in this case.

**What i tried**

```
Under menu__box, float: right;
Under menu__box, change left: -100%; to right: -100%;
```

as well as removing the -

Answer (score 0):

i changed

```css
#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

to

```css
#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__box {
  right: 0 !important;
}
```

and then changed left: -100%; to right: -100%;

i completely looked over this line of code, i apologise but hope someone else gets helped